# SOQL Lookup failing to retrieve values

Tags: soql, rest-api, lookup, python

I have following query that I am trying to run:

```
select X__Region__r.Name,  Operating_Unit__c from X__Worker__c where (X__Worker_Status_Current_WA__c = 'Active')
```

Where X__Region__c is a lookup to the Region table and Name is the value that I trying to retrieve. But I am getting this value returned:

> OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'X__Region__c),
>   (u'url',
>   u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/X__Region__c/aKR0O0000008OIKWA2')])),
>   (u'Name', u'AMER')])

The value that I am hoping to get is in the string above - AMER but the way it is being displayed is not correct as you can see. How do I modify my query?

Comment: Are you using Rest client to run this querry?

Comment: It's some species of Python REST client, probably `simple_salesforce`.

Answer (score 4):

That's just how the Salesforce API returns cross-relationship data (as unpacked into `OrderedDict` structures in Python).

It looks like you tried to get the property `X__Region__c` from the top-level object that you queried, because the content you're seeing here:

> OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'X__Region__c), (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/X__Region__c/aKR0O0000008OIKWA2')])), (u'Name', u'AMER')])

is actually the representation of a *nested object* - specifically, the related `X__Region__c` object. You need to descend another level in your data structure to access its `Name` field.

If you run a query from the API and look at the entire raw JSON response, it'll be more illuminating. Here's an example.

> GET /services/data/v43.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+Name,+Account.Name+FROM+Contact+LIMIT+1

```
{
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Contact",
      "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/0033600001aXXXXAAA"
    },
    "Id" : "0033600001aXXXXAAA",
    "Name" : "Jim Testerson",
    "Account" : {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Account",
        "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/0013600001eXXXXAAI"
      },
      "Name" : "Testcorp"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Note how the `Account` data is nested inside a second level JSON object, whose structure is the same as the top-level `Contact` object you requested. The `OrderedDict` structure used by, e.g., `simple_salesforce` in Python mirrors this structure, and it applies anywhere you're using dotted relationship paths in this way.

This is one of many areas of Salesforce where insights from SQL will lead you astray. The API returns structured JSON, *not* a flat table.